# R stairstep without upwards line after last data point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a cumulative step function, and I want to suppress the behavior of the line jumping up after the last row in dataset. This happens both in base R and ggplot2.

Is there a way to do it without specifying xlim to exclude the jump upwards?

```
data = data.frame(V1 = c(-0.1, 0, 0, 1, 1.1), V2 = c(0, 0, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3))
```

base R

```
plot(data$V1, cumsum(data$V2), type="s")
```

[image: Stairstep plot in base R]

ggplot2

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=V1, y=cumsum(V2))) +
  geom_step()
```

[image: Stairstep plot in ggplot2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the step function works seems correct to me, if you take `sum(data$V2)` that is 1.3 and that is where your line ends. It is also identical to `tail(cumsum(data$V2), 1)`. However, if you insist on not drawing the last line segment, you can set the last value of `data$V2` to 0. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data = data.frame(V1 = c(-0.1, 0, 0, 1, 1.1), V2 = c(0, 0, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3))

ggplot(data, aes(x = V1, y = cumsum(c(head(V2, -1), 0)))) +
  geom_step()
```

[image]

Note that the example doesn't generalise to multiple groups; pre-processing the data should help then.